Counting four-digit numbers divisible by 5 with specific restrictions
How many four-digit numbers divisible by 5 can be formed using the digits 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 if repetition is not allowed and the digits 0 and 1 are not allowed to be placed next to each other?Note that a number does not start with 0.

I started by counting all possibilities ignoring the restriction that 0 and 1 may not be adjacent. For this, I considered numbers with last digit 0 and last digit 5 separately. I got $60$ numbers ending in $0$ ($5 \times 4\times 3 \times 1 = 60$) and $48$ ending in $5$ ($4 \times 4\times 3 \times 1 = 48$). That is a total of $108$ numbers.
I then counted how many numbers has an adjacent 0 and 1 digits, that is, $21$ and subtracted this from the total 108 to get 87 as the final answer.
Is this correct?

Your original post (with final answer $75$) was wrong, but this is now correct. For completeness, you might want to show how you counted the $21$.

@ChrisLewis Thanks

Your solution is correct, but you can also count it directly. First, count numbers ending in zero (you can't choose $1$ for the penultimate slot nor $0$ for the first one, but the rest are free, so $3 \times 4 \times 4 = 48$). Then, count numbers ending in five.

If the digit $0$ does not occur: $4 \times 3 \times 2 = 24$.
$\underline{} \, \underline{0} \, \underline{} \, \underline{5}$: you can't choose $1$ to be in either of the open slots, so $3 \times 2 = 6$.
$\underline{} \, \underline{} \, \underline{0} \, \underline{5}$: you can't choose $1$ to be next to zero, so $3 \times 3 = 9$.

Summing it up, you get $87$ possible numbers.
